# On Querying to firebase database datasnapshot retrives old value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

New value is set to firebase database (Checked on firebase console) but on query datasnapshot retrives old value.

```
final Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(DEVICES_TABLE).orderByChild("deviceUniqueId").equalTo(deviceUniqueId);
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Device device;
        if (dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().hasNext()) {
            device = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next().getValue(Device.class);
            if (device.getIsEnable() == 1) {
                loginView.onError(loginView.getContext().getString(R.string.error_device_disable));
                doCyberoamLogout(mUserName, location);
            } else {
                switch (mMessage) {
                    case CYBEROAM_LOGIN_SUCCESS_MESSAGE:
                        //login successful
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Cyberoam login success.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                getEmailUsingCyberoamId(mUserName, mPasswod);
                            }
                        }, 5000);
                        break;
                    case CYBEROAM_WRONG_PASSWORD:
                        signOutFromFirebase();
                        loginView.onError(CYBEROAM_WRONG_PASSWORD);
                        break;
                    case CYBEROAM_MAX_LOGIN_LIMIT:
                        signOutFromFirebase();
                        loginView.onError(loginView.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.prompt_max_login_limit));
                        break;
                    default:
                        signOutFromFirebase();
                        loginView.onError(loginView.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.action_cyberoam_login_failed));
                        break;
                }
            }
            query.removeEventListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

});
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: are you sure you are fetching the updated data? and not before the updation or device had proper internet connection to load new data and not from cached db info

Comment: Did the persistence is enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line :

```
query.removeEventListener(this);
```

When persistence is enabled **addValueEventListener** returns cached data first and the next time the new data.